# Error "0 params bound not matching -1 required" while fatching data from informix using ibm_db_dbi driver

Tags: python-3.x, flask, informix

I have created an flask application and connected informix db using ibm_db_dbi driver after enabling DRDA port.

I am able to extract data from db but when I tried multiple hits to single api at a time then i got error like : "0 params bound not matching -1 required" and response code is 401

```
Informix connection file :-


    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.connection = db.connect("DATABASE=%s;HOSTNAME=%s;PORT=%s;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=%s;PWD=%s;" % (
                self.Informix_DATABASE, self.Informix_HOSTNAME, self.Informix_PORT, self.Informix_UID,
                self.Informix_PWD), "", "")
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        except db.Error as e:
            logger.error('Informix Connection error in main db: %s', e._message)


    def query(self, query):
        if(self.connection != ""):
            try:
                self.cursor.execute(query)
                return self.cursor.fetchall()
            except db.Error as e:
                logger.error('DB001 error in query : %s', e._message)



    def __del__(self):
        if (self.connection != ""):
            self.connection.close()
```

Error logging file :-

2019-07-20 07:03:17 INFO     [_internal.py : 122] XX.XXX.X.XX - - [20/Jul/2019 07:03:17] "GET /api/shift_details?date=2019-07-21&uid=XXXXXXX HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2019-07-20 07:03:17 ERROR    [Informix_Conn.py : 66] QRY001 error in query : SELECT serial_number, employee_name, shift_date, shiftpatternguid, pattern_start_time, pattern_end_time, shift_status_id FROM dots.v_pending WHERE serial_number = 'XXXXXXX' and  shift_date = '2019-07-22' limit 1;

2019-07-20 07:03:17 ERROR    [Informix_Conn.py : 69] DB001 error in query : 0 params bound not matching -1 required

2019-07-20 07:03:17 INFO     [_internal.py : 122] XX.XXX.X.XX - - [20/Jul/2019 07:03:17] "GET /api/shift_details?date=2019-07-22&uid=XXXXXXX HTTP/1.1" 401 -

2019-07-20 07:03:17 INFO     [_internal.py : 122] XX.XXX.X.XX - - [20/Jul/2019 07:03:17] "GET /api/shift_details?date=2019-07-23&uid=XXXXXXX HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2019-07-20 07:03:17 INFO     [_internal.py : 122] XX.XXX.X.XX - - [20/Jul/2019 07:03:17] "GET /api/shift_details?date=2019-07-25&uid=XXXXXXX HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2019-07-20 07:03:17 INFO     [_internal.py : 122] XX.XXX.X.XX - - [20/Jul/2019 07:03:17] "GET /api/shift_details?date=2019-07-24&uid=XXXXXXX HTTP/1.1" 200 -

2019-07-20 07:03:17 ERROR    [Informix_Conn.py : 66] QRY001 error in query : SELECT id, username, password, rolename FROM dots.v_api_user_details where id = 3

2019-07-20 07:03:17 ERROR    [Informix_Conn.py : 69] DB001 error in query : 0 params bound not matching -1 required

2019-07-20 07:03:17 ERROR    [**init**.py : 136] Invalid JWT. User does not exist

2019-07-20 07:03:17 INFO     [_internal.py : 122] XX.XXX.X.XX - -

[20/Jul/2019 07:03:17] "GET /api/shift_details?date=2019-07-27&uid=XXXXXXX HTTP/1.1" 401 -

Answer (score 1):

The Informix native python drier (IfxPy) has better support with Informix database and it is well tested and maintained. The ibm_db has many limitation including some of the datatypes.

https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy